# "Fast forward effect" in Mad Max

Tags: effects, mad-max

In [Mad Max](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079501/) and [Mad Max 2 (The Road Warrior)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082694/), there are several scenes (often fast scenes, like car chases), where the film seems to be running on "fast forward". The characters move very quick and it looks very unnatural.

Did they do this on purpose? Or is this just a byproduct of trying to make an action scene seem "faster" than it actually is?

I also heard that many car chases (in general) are filmed very slowly and then speed up afterwards, to make it seem real. Was the movie attempting to do so, too?

Comment: I have noticed this, in this movie in particular. It has always looked awful. This was a great movie, but go look on youtube at the kid with the boomerang when he cuts off one of Humungous' men's hands. They speed it up there and it just look absolutely absurd.

Comment: This also exist in Mad Max Fury Road. Right from the start chasing scenes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, George Miller used sped up footage a great deal when filming his trilogy, especially during the first film (to a lesser extent in the third).

This is indeed a standard trick used by filmmakers to make the action seem faster-paced, and is used primarily during chases and stunt work which could result in serious injury should the stunt performer fall from the car at a greater speed.

While watching Mad Max (and The Road Warrior), I am always struck by the length of some of the sequences Miller uses in his car scenes, including many extended cuts. When ramped up (sped up) footage is used in these instances it is easier for the viewer to spot unnatural movements from the humans in the vehicles, thus resulting in the 'fast forward' effect that you have noticed.